# Too many EIO socket.io polling calls slowing the web page

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My application is based on Socket.io to have a chat functionality.

My application is deployed on red hat open shift.

I keep getting http://url/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lj8huKr&sid=y1OB9OBmdSd_Ma4nAAFG requests which are huge in number.

And they are probably also blocking the loading of my web page which is slowing my web page.

I read in the internet that this error comes if the port is not mentioned. But my port number is coming of red hat open shift configuration page.

Below is the code of how socket.io is intialized in my initial html page the node js initial server page

index.html

```
var socket =io();
```

index.js (node js server)

```
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(process.env.NODE_PORT || 3006, process.env.NODE_IP || 'localhost', function(){
    console.log('listening on port 3006');
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In socket.io-client v1.x, the initial connection will start as `polling` so you will always see at least some requests to the `http://site.url/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling` URL.

Socket.io clients will then attempt to upgrade to a websocket connection. Those clients that can't upgrade will remain polling regularly to get as close to real time as they can. If you have a large number of clients that are polling every 2 seconds then you will see a lot of requests.

v2.x+ clients moved to using websockets first, but will fallback to the same long polling a URL if the websocket connection fails.